# Computing the outer flux $\int\int_S F\cdot ds$

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute $$\int\int_S F\cdot ds$$ where $F=f(|r|)r$, $r=<x,y,z>$, $f(|r|)=\frac{1}{|r|^2}$, $|r|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, and $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=2\}$.

So, basically I have to evaluate the integral with respect to $S^+$ and $S^-$ and sum up them. where $S^+$ is the upper hemisphere $z>1$, $S^-$ is the lower one.

For $S^+$, I have $z=\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}+1$ and $ds=r_x\times r_ydA$. and $$r_x\times r_y=<-z_x,-z_y,1>$$ so $$F\cdot ds=f(|r|)(-xz_x-yz_y+z)dA\\=f(|r|)(\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}}+\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}+1)dA$$

and I have to integrate this in the domain $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq2\}$.

And $f(|r|)=\frac{1}{|r|^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{1}{3+2\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}}$.

Now let $x=u\cos v$, $y=u \sin v$. $0<u\leq\sqrt2$, $0<v\leq2\pi$. So I have $$F\cdot ds = \frac{1}{3+2\sqrt{2-u^2}}(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2-u^2}}+\sqrt{2-u^2}+1)dudv$$ since there's no $v$ variable, I can factor it out with $2\pi$, and I got only single integration with respect to $u$. But it's too messy to integrate by hand, so I might have some mistakes or something. Am I on the right track? If I am, then how do I calculate this? Otherwise, how can I fix it?

Btw, is this right on the lower hemisphere?: $ds=r_y\times r_x dA$ (since it needs to be outer?)